# adding sliding effect or animation in page swiping, Ipad

Tags: jquery

I am using swipe planes to swipe pages in Ipad.
http://swipeplanes-jquery.blogspot.in/

Its working perfectly on my Ipad. But the swiping is very fast without any sliding effect.

This is how I am calling the sliding function

```
$('.class1').swipePlanes();
```

Does anyone know how to insert some sliding effect or animation in this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looking at its source code, I'd guess that you would have to modify the library in order to do what you intend. The page change code is in the function *irPagina()*; it seems to be adding a 500ms transition effect; you should take a look to see why that's not working on the iPad.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to "jquery.swipeplanes-1.2.js" :

```
setInterval(function()
{           
    if(pagActual < metaPagNum)
        pagActual++;
    else
        pagActual = 0;
    irPagina();     
}, 6000);
```

before function `generarControles(divVisor,metaPagNum)`

It's work for me (you can change this `6000ms`)